# Is this a good way for Controller to interact with Model ? (MVC)

Tags: php, mvc

In my controller I had the idea to do something like the following:

```
// retrieve fields from form
$firstname = $form->getInput('firstname');
$lastname = $form->getInput('lastname');
[...]
// create Member object
$member = new Member($firstname, $lastname, [...]);
// save Member in DB
$this->_daoFactory->get('Member')->save($member);
```

In this example, the DAO factory would create an instance of the MemberDAO class, which (I guess) acts like a data mapper? And allows me to save the Member object in DB, to update a Member, get a Member from id, and other db requests probably.

What do you think about this code?

Thank you for your review!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of MVC frameworks do the datamapping in the same class (usually with static methods).  I would also avoid creating hard links between controllers and models (like having each model property as a parameter in the class constructor).  Something like this is a little more elegant, IMO:

```
<?php

// Model
class Member
{
    public static function forge(array $data = array())
    {
        return new static($data);
    }

    public function __construct(array $data = array())
    {
        foreach ($data as $k => $v)
        {
            // consider checking here for expected properties,
            // sanitizing input, etc.
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }

    public function save()
    {
        // If primary key exists, run DB update query
        // Otherwise, run insert query

        // Return success/failure information (and/or throw exceptions)
    }
}

// Controller action
$member = Member::forge($form->get_sanitized_postdata());
$member->save();
```

Comment: Why didn't you instantiate with "new" operator instead?
$member = new Member($form->get_sanitized_postdata());